# What XPath can I use to get all text nodes after and including the first paragraph node?

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I'm new to Nokogiri, and Ruby in general.

I want to get the text of all the nodes in the document, starting from and inclusive of the first paragraph node.

I tried the following with XPath but I'm getting nowhere:

```
 puts page.search("//p[0]/text()[next-sibling::node()]")
```

This doesn't work. What do I have to change?

Comment: It's important to supply a small sample of the XML in question.

Comment: http://www.zeit.de/wirtschaft/2013-04/produkte-schwachstellen-garantie-hersteller

Comment: No, not a link to your sample, put a sample of it in the question, large enough to demonstrate the problem and no larger. A link makes us chase down the information we need to help you, and, because we do this voluntarily, in our spare time, you are making us do extra work to help you. Don't do that.  Also, links break, making your question worthless for people searching for the same question in the future.

Comment: @theTinMan , okay sorry about the link,, I'm using that page, as the sample so I provided the whole page as is, anyways in the future, ill make sure i do what you say. Jens Erat has already provided me with a solution that works, so I dont think you need to spend anymore time on it. I would also like to say , that i have learnt a lot from your various answers dealing with Nokogiri and Xpath, so I will definitely be coming back with more questions for you. Thanks again, bye.

Comment: @theTinMan, as promised I have another perplexing issue with Nokogiri, I hope you can help me. Here is the link to the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931848/nokogiri-automatically-introducing-line-breaks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to find the `<p/>` node and return all `text()` nodes, both inside and following. Depending what XPath capabilities Nokogiri has, use one of these queries:

```
//p[1]/(descendant::text() | following::text())
```

If it doesn't work, use this instead, which needs to find the first paragraph twice and can be a little bit, but probably unnoticeably, slower:

```
(//p[1]/descendant::text() | //p[1]/following::text())
```

A probably unsupported XPath 2.0 alternative would be:

```
//text()[//p[1] << .]
```

which means "all text nodes preceded by the first `<p/>` node in document".

Comment: +1, but note that only your second expression works with Nokogiri.

Comment: That's what I expected, thus I provided multiple. I'm not sure if the first is valid XPath 1.0 but not supported on nokogiri or whether it is XPath 2.0, too. As the last is the most elegant version to write that query, I included it anyway.

Comment: @JensErat ,, thanks a ton dude, it worked like a charm. Just one more thing, the task i have is parsing these German webpages , and then basically splitting the article content into sentences and then words, my problem there is regex oriented. I can get the job done in English, but I dont know what to do in German, what is the best practice while splitting german characters. ( my regex gets mucked up with the umlauts and the eszets, ) i have tried both the \p{l} and \X modifiers in php , but no luck. If you or anyone else feels that they can help me with this I'd provide the full example.thnx

Comment: I guess you should ask a new question to get somebody more familiar with XPath in PHP. If you're able to use another XPath/XQuery engine, think about using XQuery Full Text like provided by [BaseX](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Full-Text) and lots of other XQuery engines. It could save you lots of hassles with tokenization.

Answer (score 2):

This works with Nokogiri (which stands on top of [libxml2](http://www.xmlsoft.org) and supports XPath 1.0 expressions):

```xpath
//p[1]//text() | //p[1]/following::text()
```

Proof:

```ruby
require 'nokogiri'

html = '<body><h1>A</h1><p>B <b>C</b></p><p>D <b>E</b></p></body>'
doc = Nokogiri.HTML(html)

p doc.xpath('//p[1]//text() | //p[1]/following::text()').map(&:text)
#=> ["B ", "C", "D ", "E"]
```

Note that just selecting the text nodes themselves returns a [`NodeSet`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html) of [`Nokogiri::XML::Text`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Text.html) objects, and so if you want only the text contents of them you must map them via the `.text` (or `.content`) methods.

Comment: This looks about right but I don't think the [1] is necessary

Comment: @Phrogz, +1, thanks this works as well. please could you help with my other question (ive added it as a comment, below jens erat's answer)